# Getting multiple instance of same modal in ionic 2/3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, hybrid

Inside my app.component , I have a background mode service which when shared via intent throws value to a behaviour Subject

```
this._notification.setNotiService2(data.extras);
```

Once logged In , I am setting the root to TabsPage

```
this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot('TabsPage');
```

On Tabs Page , I have subscribed to the behaviour subject , so whenever I get a shared object , I process it and open a Modal displaying the required values. 
Initally when the app opens , everything works fine. But once we login/logout the problem occurs. On logging out , I am setting the root page as Login Page.

```
this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot('LoginPage');
```

Then again on successful login setting root to Tabs Page

```
 this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot('TabsPage');
```

Now again if I share the values via intent multiple instances of the Modal are opening with the exact same values.
I have checked for behaviour subject as being null/undefined but the subscribed value is Ok only . Logging the value from behaviour Subject inside the TabsPage , I found the same function (subscribed behaviour subject) is being called twice.

Again if I logout/login the Modal opens 3 times and the number continues to grow accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me, that you are not remembering to unsubscribe, which means that the subscriptions increment each time. So whenever you leave a page, remember to unsubscribe to (all) your subscriptions. Since you are using Ionic, the `ionViewWillLeave` hook would be a suitable place to unsubscribe... so declare a new Subscription on your page and...

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

// ...

mySubscription = new Subscription();

// ...

this.mySubscription = this.myService.mySubject.subscribe(....)

// ...  

ionViewWillLeave() { 
  this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```